# Huagati DBML/EDMX for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

The Huagati tool was discontinued and doesn't install on Visual Studio 2013. I had used a posting (I believe on Huagati's site) on how to install it manually but I can't find it anymore. Anyone know where it is or how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The latest version will install itself in VS2013 too (as well as in 2008/2010/2012).

Answer (score 2):

couldn't find the post but figured it out.

- install Huagati DBML/EDMX tools as you normally would with the msi
- look for the file "HuagatiDBMLTool2012.Addin" in the installation
  folder (usually C:\Program Files (x86)\Huagati Systems Co Ltd\Huagati
  DBML_EDMX Tools\VS2010)
- make a copy called "HuagatiDBMLTools2013.Addin" and update the version
  tag to 12.0
- In VisualStudio 2013, TOOLS -> Options -> Add-in Security and then
  add the path to the VS2010 folder (usually C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Huagati Systems Co Ltd\Huagati DBML_EDMX Tools\VS2010)
- restart VisualStudio 2013 and it should work